# Get "????????" from Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, encoding

When I exec my procedure I get `??????????` character instead of Hebrew character.

The code in procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE #myTempTable   
(
    [ya_id] [int],
    [ya_title] [varchar](200) NULL,
    RowNumber [int]
)

set @sql ='insert INTO #myTempTable
    select [ya_id],
    [ya_title],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ya_date desc)
FROM   y_ads join ezorim on e_id=ya_e_id join y_cat on ya_yc_id=yc_id'
exec(@sql)


/*Ads*/
SELECT [ya_id],
    [ya_title],
from #myTempTable 
where RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 24
```

The encoding of the sql server: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

p.s. the other dynamic tables from the procedure return correct character, just that dynamic table returns `??????????`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `NVARCHAR`, which can hold Unicode characters.

Comment: the column is nvarcher, so it is not the answer

Comment: the temp table column is not.